# matlab read specific numbers from matrix

Tags: matlab, readfile

Here is my issue:

I have a file that contains the following data (sample):

```
kptn wtk kptc(3) eiglist(:)
1 1.00000 0.0000 -0.5000 0.0000 -8.65212 -8.65212 -2.54501 -2.54501
2 1.00000 0.0000 -0.4500 0.0000 -9.31361 -7.93027 -3.19370 -3.19370
3 1.00000 0.0000 -0.4000 0.0000 -9.90932 -7.14566 -3.77996 -3.77996
4 1.00000 0.0000 -0.3500 0.0000 -10.43755 -6.30634 -4.30047 -4.30047
```

For my plot I only need the very first number (1..number of lines minus the first one) as X value, and the numbers after the 5th number in a line as my Y values. So per every line I would have multiple Y values. So in the end for every line I should have something like this:

```
X=[1], Y=[-8.65212, -8.65212, -2.54501, -2.54501]
```

second line:

```
X=[2], Y=[-9.31361, -7.93027, -3.19370, -3.19370]
```

However, the number of Y values may vary from file to file, but the number of values between X and Y will always be 4.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index into a matrix directly to get the values you want.

In your case, this would look like the following:

```
Data = [1 1.00000 0.0000 -0.5000 0.0000 -8.65212 -8.65212 -2.54501 -2.54501;
2 1.00000 0.0000 -0.4500 0.0000 -9.31361 -7.93027 -3.19370 -3.19370;
3 1.00000 0.0000 -0.4000 0.0000 -9.90932 -7.14566 -3.77996 -3.77996;
4 1.00000 0.0000 -0.3500 0.0000 -10.43755 -6.30634 -4.30047 -4.30047]

%// As for your comment, to start from line 2 use `Data(2:end,whatever)`
DatatoPlot = [Data(2:end,1) Data(2:end,6:end)]; %// Get the appropriate data using indexing
```

Using square brackets [] tells Matlab to concatenate data, i.e. put all the data one after the other in the order you specify (here horizontally);

Hence `DatatoPlot` looks like this:

```
DatatoPlot =

    1.0000   -8.6521   -8.6521   -2.5450   -2.5450
    2.0000   -9.3136   -7.9303   -3.1937   -3.1937
    3.0000   -9.9093   -7.1457   -3.7800   -3.7800
    4.0000  -10.4375   -6.3063   -4.3005   -4.3005
```

Then you can plot the result (or use `scatter` as well):

```
%// Display the result
figure
hold on
for k = 1:size(DatatoPlot,1)

plot(k,DatatoPlot(k,2:end),'*-') %// Y values correspond to 2nd column until the end.

end

xlim([0 5]) %// To see data more clearly
set(gca,'Xtick',[1:5])
```

Giving this:

[image]

Which you can customize as you need of course.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you can use `importdata` to load your data. For example:

```
filename = YourFileName;
delimiterIn = ' '; %// Values are separated by a white space
headerlinesIn = 1; %// There is 1 headerline, which you want to skip.

Data = importdata(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
```

Now Data should be a numeric array since all values are numbers. If it's a cell array, you can use `cell2mat` to convert it to a numeric array.

Comment: How would I populate DATA from file skipping the first line?

Comment: Please see the edited answer. You need to use Data(2:end,whatever) to start from line 2

Comment: I get that. But after I open file fid=fopen('filename'), how do I put data from file into DATA. Because you populated DATA manually. Sorry if I'm missing something, but this is my first ever try at Matlab.

Comment: alright I just updated my answer. You probably want to use "importdata".

Answer (score 0):

first, why not cut the first 5 numbers off your sample matrix if the distance between X and Y is always 4?

```
M = sample(:,6:end)
```

your X is the first Column, so

```
X = sample(:,1)
```

Now you can plot your Y for every X

```
figure
for n = 1:length(X)
   plot(whatever you wish to plot)
end
```